# Update contact phonetic name - android API level 19 (4.4.3)

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to add phonetic name to specific contact.

I am doing the following:

```
ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                      .withSelection(Data._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ContactId)})
                      .withValue(CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME, "mois")
                      .build());

            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

But Although I get no error - contact doesn't updated.

Any Idea?

Comment: silly question, but just to rule out: permissions?

Comment: I have all permissions . why silly?

Comment: did you try to query by the ContactId and see that you get a valid cursor? `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
          Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
          new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);`

Comment: and by the way, I meant **my** question about permissions was silly, but I guess no question is silly :)

Comment: I able to add Mail And phone but not NickName and Phonetic name

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if the permissions are set correctly and updating other stuff works, I think the problem is wrong ID in the selection (contact vs. raw_contact vs. data).

Try:

`withSelection(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(RawContactId)})`